# Unmarshaling with camel:base64 returns wrong binary

Tags: base64, apache-camel

I'm using the `<base64>` element to unmarshal base64 code that comes as part of an XML. The route looks like this:

```
<route>
  <split streaming="true" strategyRef="myAggregationStaregy">
    <xpath>/*/*</xpath>
    <choice>
      <when>
        <xpath>//record</xpath>
        <to uri="file:/record.xml" />
      </when>

      <when>
        <xpath>//content</xpath>

        <unmarshal>
          <base64 />
        </unmarshal>

        <to uri="file:/content.bin" />
      </when>
    </choice>
  </split>
</route>
```

While the XML splitting works fine the `<unmarshal>` task returns rubbish. The result binary is exacly of the expected size but the bytes themselves are completely wrong.

**Attempts:**

- Applying the `lineSeparator` and `lineLength` options had no effect.
- When omitting the `<unmarshal>` block in the route and transforming the resulting base64 code by hand (linux `base64` command) I receive the correct binary.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I found the solution:
I expected the `<xpath>//content</xpath>` statement to filter the incoming XML so that the message body containes only the part inside the `content` element.

But this was wrong. This "xpath" statement is the "when" statement's predicate and it does no filtering at all.

In order to achieve the intended behaviour I had to explicitly extract my XML's "content" part and write it to the message body (using a "setBody" statement). My route finally looks like this:

```
<route>
  <split>
    <xpath>/*/*</xpath>
    <choice>
      <when>
        <xpath>//record</xpath>
        <to uri="file:/record.xml" />
      </when>

      <when>
        <xpath>//content</xpath>

        <setBody><xpath>//content/text()</xpath></setBody>

        <unmarshal>
          <base64 />
        </unmarshal>

        <to uri="file:/content.bin" />
      </when>
    </choice>
  </split>
</route>
```